# PSQL ON UPDATE interaction with multi-column foreign key

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

So, I have been tasked with setting up a new DB to handle server patching. I'm still in the design phase and I've been unable to find something to answer this question so I'm reaching out for help.

I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE servers (
    name varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    patch_id varchar(10) REFERENCES patch_info(id) NOT NULL,
    env varchar(5),
    ...
)

CREATE TABLE patch_info (
    id varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    patch_time timestamptz NOT NULL,
    reboot_time timestamptz NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE patch_data (
    id big serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(50),
    patch_id varchar(10),
    env varchar(5),
    FOREIGN KEY (name, patch_id, env) REFERENCES servers (name, patch_id, env) NOT NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

My question is what is the behavior if I update the patch_id in the servers table. the patch_info table basically just contains a full list of patch/reboot time identifiers referenced by the id value in other tables. The actual patch_info table itself will only change once a month when the ids are updated to reflect time/dates in the current month, but individual servers frequently change their times on a month to month basis, so when the patch_id field changes in the servers table that change needs to cascade down to the patch_data table.

The other question was about the ON DELETE option. I want the patch_data table to cascade a delete if the actual server.name field is deleted, but not if the patch_id is null or removed. Is this the current behavior of my ON CASCADE ON DELETE statement or can I use the patch_data.name column in two separate foreign keys?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will need a unique or primary key constraint on `servers (name, patch_id, env)`, since every foreign key must reference either a primary or a unique key.

`ON UPDATE CASCADE` will update the `patch_id` column (there are no "fields" in tables) in `patch_data` if you update `patch_id` in `servers`.

`ON DELETE CASCADE` will delete rows in `patch_data` if you delete the referenced row from `servers`.

You cannot "delete a field". Perhaps you mean "update the column to NULL". If the constraint on `servers` is a primary key constraint, then you cannot do that, because primary key columns are not nullable. If it is a unique constraint, and you update `patch_id` to NULL in `servers`, the referencing rows in `patch_data` will also have `patch_id` set to NULL. The consequence of that is that the foreign key relationship is no longer effective, because foreign keys are only enforced for columns that are not NULL.

If that sounds confusing, right you are. Consequently, make sure that all involved columns are defined `NOT NULL`, then nothing weird can happen.

Comment: yes, there are no fields, I should watch my terminology when posting for help or answering, thank you. So I need to create an actual unique key in servers table comprised of (name, patch_id, env) in order to then reference that set of columns in another table? I take it then that having name as the PK for servers is not sufficient because patch_id and env can both have multiple entries for different servers?

Comment: It is a technical requirement: a foreign key must point to a primary or unique key. I gather you want to have the foreign key only for the automatic update. Why do you want to duplicate the column?

Comment: It's necessary for auditing purposes. The plan initially was to use the name and patch_id from servers to populate the patch_data table with the name, patch_id, env, as well as patch_time and reboot_time from patch_info. Is it possible to use the servers PK as part of a separate unique constraint? Keep name as the PK but then add CONSTRAINT my_constraint UNIQUE (name, env, patch_id) as a constraint to be referenced from other tables? The table patch_data is going to be "public" facing, while the others will all be locked down, which is why it needs to be fully dependent on the other tables.

Comment: Yes, you can add a superfluous unique constraint that contains the primary key. I question the need for redundant data for "auditing purposes". Auditing, as I understand it, is collecting data that answer the question who did what when. I don't see how keeping duplicated data can serve that purpose. I predict that you will have much more fun with your database if you avoid that kind of data duplication and the need to synchronize them that led to this question.